# Prove that a integral tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $x\in(0,2\pi)$. I want to show
$$\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{2\sin{\frac{t}{2}}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)\sin \frac{(2n+1)t}{2}\ \,dt$$
tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. I know that we can use Riemann-Lesbegue lemma. But I want to do it without Lesbegue lemma and argue elementarily.  I tried to integrate indefinitely and use fundamental theorem of calculus. But fail to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by the Lebesgue lemma? There are several results that go by that name

Comment: @Reveillark Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I(x)$ be given by

$$I(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{2\sin({\frac{t}{2}})}-\frac{1}{t}\right)\sin \left(\frac{(2n+1)t}{2}\right) \,dt$$

Note that $\displaystyle f(t)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sin({t/2})}-\frac{1}{t}\right)=\frac t{24}+O(t^3)$ as $\displaystyle t\to0$.

Now, integrate by parts with $\displaystyle u=f(t)$ and $\displaystyle v=\frac{\cos((2n+1)t)}{-(2n+1)}$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Did you mean $t/2$ in your substitution?

Comment: I have edited since the first post and now don't enforce any substitution.

Comment: @Mark Viola. I tried integration by parts, there are huge complicated terms? In essence, the most important things is the degree 1 n polynomial  so that as n tends to infinity and the whole sum tends to zero?

Comment: @user72342343 $u=f(t)$, $dv=\sin((2n+1)t)$.  Then, $du=f'(t)\,dt$ and $v=-\cos((2n+1)t)/(2n+1)$.  The term $f'(t)=\frac1{24}+O(t^2)$ is a "nice" function.  Does this help?

Comment: @Mark Viola Could use explain more on $O(t^3)$? since I have no knowledge or have not seen $O(t^3)$

Comment: You can read about [Big O Notation Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).  In heuristic terms, the order of the next term in the taylor expansion of $f(t)$ is $t^3$.  Suffice to say that $f(t)$ has a removeable discontinuity at $0$ that once removed renders it a smooth continuously differentiable function.

Comment: @ Mark Viola Would you mind doing it without the Big O notation? Would appreciate it  if you can elaborate more on your answer. Thanks a lot. I am a self-taught old man without much mathematical maturity, just self-studying elementary math

Comment: @user72342343 Just know that $f(t)$ is a nice smooth function.  To find the limit as $n\to\infty$, you don't have to know what it is.  Then, can you proceed?

Comment: @ Mark Viola What do you mean by nice smooth function? infinitely many times differentiable?

Comment: Yes, it is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @Mark Viola How does infinitely differentiable link to the tendency to zero?

Comment: Well, when we integrate by parts, the term $\frac1{2n+1}$ appears in both the $uv$ part and the $\int v\,du$ part.  Both $uv$ and $\int v\,du$ approach $0$ because of the $\frac1{2n+1}$ term